# jQuery check and change/add parameters in the href

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to read all the href elements on my website and do the following:

1. check if url has any parameters starting with `?location=123` or `&location=123` (123 will change randomly). If it has any of those, change the location=123 to location=456
2. if it cannot find any of of those, check if url has ?. If so add &location=456 or else add ?location=456

I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337376/5675125 code:

```
$('html').on('mouseover', 'body', function(){
// do something
$('a').attr('href', function() {
        return (this.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) ? this.href + "&location=/123/" : this.href + "?location=/123/";
});

});
```

However, This returns this:

> http://myurl.com.comhttp://myurl.com/?location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc&location=/123/abc

Which as you can see, has the original url + original url plus hundreds of parameters added.

how do i perform this check, with the regex for the 123 bit.

UPDATE:

To check if the url contains the '?'

I am using:

```
 var link = $(this).attr('href');
    if(link.indexOf("?") >= 0){
        link.attr('href', 'YESiContainAQuestionMark');
    } else {
        link.attr('href', 'NOiDoNotContainAQuestionMark');
    }
```

but all I am getting in the console is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined(…)

Answer (score 0):

Your mouseover function will trigger many many times... Just use `$(document).ready` to do the replacement once on pageload. So instead of

```
$('html').on('mouseover', 'body', function(){
```

use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('href', function() {
        return (this.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) ? this.href + "&location=/123/" : this.href + "?location=/123/";
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the specific string, and if that doesn't work, add it:

```
$('a').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var newhref = href.replace('location=123', 'location=456');
  if (href == newhref) {
    if (href.includes('?')) {
      newhref += '&location=456'
    } else {
      newhref += '?location=456'
    }
  }
  $(this).attr('href', newhref);
});
```

Comment: This does not work. There seems to be nothing changing at all with the URLS. and also: there is no regex for the 123 to be anything.

Comment: but thannk you for the reply

Answer (score -1):

You may find it useful to gather the URL & and all the query string parameters, and then work with the parameters.

```
    let urlParams;
    (window.onpopstate = function() {
        let match,
            pl = /\+/g, // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
            search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
            decode = function(s) {
                return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "));
            },
            query = window.location.search.substring(1);

        urlParams = {};
        while (match = search.exec(query))
            urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
    })();
    let myLocation =  urlParams.location
```

[see original post ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript#answer-2880929)